# Rachmaninoff Piano Concerto 2 without piano

Tags: piano

I'm currently learning this piece and would like to play it along with a record. Where can I find orchestra only variant?

Comment: **Hello and welcome to Music.SE!** Question like this likely to be closed due it's off-topic. Please check what's on-topic on the site. Thank you!

Comment: These type of questions are off topic currently, but you could try asking in [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/440/the-practice-room). This question likely will be on topic for the [Music Fans SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61574/music-fans), which is currently waiting for more people to sign up.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate of what should be the "canonical" question of this type. There are many different options listed as answers; if I were you I would look towards SmartMusic as the most likely solution.